# Why the number of threads growing higher than expected?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test case with just one HTTP request. The number of threads and Ramp Up period is set to 30. And i planning to do the test for 600 seconds.[image]

But looking at the JMeter output, i could see a huge number of requests generated. Why is this so? I am expecting only 60 threads in a minute to generate. Can someone suggest me how to do this?

```
S:\roshTests\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin>jmeter -n -t 
S:\roshTests\LivePerformance\June1\PPS-Proxy\catalog\catalog.jmx  -l 
S:\roshTests\LivePerformance\June1\PPS-Proxy\catalog\Output\results.csv
Writing log file to: S:\roshTests\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\jmeter.log
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using S:\roshTests\LivePerformance\June1\PPS-Proxy\catalog\catalog.jmx
Starting the test @ Fri Jun 02 05:18:04 IDT 2017 (1496369884546)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +    377 in 00:00:25 =   15.3/s Avg:   766 Min:   106 Max:  3114 Err:   198 (52.52%) Active: 25 Started: 25 Finished: 0
summary +   1364 in 00:00:30 =   45.5/s Avg:   647 Min:   144 Max:  4385 Err:  1180 (86.51%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =   1741 in 00:00:55 =   31.9/s Avg:   673 Min:   106 Max:  4385 Err:  1378 (79.15%)
summary +    985 in 00:00:30 =   32.8/s Avg:   643 Min:    88 Max:  4918 Err:   752 (76.35%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =  12859 in 00:05:25 =   39.6/s Avg:   616 Min:    88 Max:  6149 Err: 10562 (82.14%)
summary +    984 in 00:00:30 =   32.8/s Avg:   675 Min:   113 Max:  5070 Err:   762 (77.44%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =  11874 in 00:04:55 =   40.3/s Avg:   614 Min:   100 Max:  6149 Err:  9810 (82.62%)
summary +   1103 in 00:00:30 =   36.7/s Avg:   624 Min:   104 Max:  4935 Err:   884 (80.15%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =  10890 in 00:04:25 =   41.2/s Avg:   609 Min:   100 Max:  6149 Err:  9048 (83.09%)
summary +   1220 in 00:00:30 =   40.6/s Avg:   584 Min:   100 Max:  6149 Err:  1001 (82.05%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =   9787 in 00:03:55 =   41.7/s Avg:   607 Min:   100 Max:  6149 Err:  8164 (83.42%)
summary +   1336 in 00:00:30 =   44.5/s Avg:   570 Min:   106 Max:  5296 Err:  1106 (82.78%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =   8567 in 00:03:25 =   41.9/s Avg:   610 Min:   106 Max:  5643 Err:  7163 (83.61%)
summary +   1320 in 00:00:30 =   44.0/s Avg:   587 Min:   116 Max:  5187 Err:  1111 (84.17%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =   7231 in 00:02:55 =   41.4/s Avg:   618 Min:   106 Max:  5643 Err:  6057 (83.76%)
summary +   1273 in 00:00:30 =   42.5/s Avg:   637 Min:   106 Max:  5383 Err:  1072 (84.21%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =   5911 in 00:02:25 =   40.9/s Avg:   625 Min:   106 Max:  5643 Err:  4946 (83.67%)
summary +   1430 in 00:00:30 =   47.6/s Avg:   591 Min:   116 Max:  5643 Err:  1229 (85.94%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =   4638 in 00:01:55 =   40.5/s Avg:   621 Min:   106 Max:  5643 Err:  3874 (83.53%)
summary +   1467 in 00:00:30 =   48.9/s Avg:   589 Min:   119 Max:  4691 Err:  1267 (86.37%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =   3208 in 00:01:25 =   37.9/s Avg:   635 Min:   106 Max:  4691 Err:  2645 (82.45%)
summary +   1070 in 00:00:30 =   35.7/s Avg:   651 Min:    99 Max:  7324 Err:   862 (80.56%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =  13929 in 00:05:55 =   39.3/s Avg:   619 Min:    88 Max:  7324 Err: 11424 (82.02%)
summary +   1531 in 00:00:30 =   51.1/s Avg:   594 Min:   106 Max:  5194 Err:  1332 (87.00%) Active: 30 Started: 30 Finished: 0
summary =  15460 in 00:06:25 =   40.2/s Avg:   617 Min:    88 Max:  7324 Err: 12756 (82.51%)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you understand the difference between Threads and requests. amount of Threads isn't equal to requests, what you're seeing in the output is the amount of requests made by your threads, and depending on your response times it's very well possible to get that many results.

Try setting the Loop count to 1 or 2 and you'll see that the requests will even out with your calculations.

Beside that... in your output on the far right side you can see how many Threads are started.

Comment: But i need to run continuously for 10 minutes. So how i can set this up?

Comment: if you just want your 60 Threads for 10 minutes increase your threads/ramp up time to 60 and the duration to 660 seconds (if you really want 10 minutes with all 60 Threads)

Comment: Please help me here. As suggested i have made the threads to 10 and ramp up period to 60 and ran the test plan for 600 secs. So the TPS is 10. How can i increase the TPS to about 100?

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup, threads will start with one second delay.

Ramp up period is the time in which all treads should start.

You have loop set to infinite, so when all thread login after initial 30 seconds, you will always have 30 active users, and could never have more that that.

You have many more requests, depending on response time of your server, but threads are like users. If you set 30, it will always be 30. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are running 30 virtual users for 10 minutes. Each virtual user is executing [samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) **as fast as it can** (the speed mostly depends on your application response time) this is why you have a lot of requests.

If you need to limit JMeter throughput to 60 requests per second only you can do it using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer):

1. Add Constant Throughput Timer to your Test Plan
2. Set "Target Troughput" to `60`
3. Set "Calculate Troughput based on" to `All active threads`

This way JMeter will "pause" its threads (virtual users) to slow them down to 60 requests per minute.